# Change ComboBox Border Color in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

In My Application i have added Combobox as shown in below picture

[image]

i have set the combobox property as

```
cmbDatefilter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
```

And now my question is how to set border style to combobox so that it will look nice.

I verified in below link

[Flat style Combo box](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10433090/flat-style-combo-box.aspx)

My question is different from below link's.

[Generic ComboBox in Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832626/generic-combobox-in-windows-forms-application)

[How to override UserControl class to draw a custom border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908384/how-to-override-usercontrol-class-to-draw-a-custom-border)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override UserControl class to draw a custom border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908384/how-to-override-usercontrol-class-to-draw-a-custom-border)

Comment: Read the question carefully.

Comment: Windows forms controls don't have border styles, so if you want one while keeping the flat style, you will have to draw it yourself.

Comment: first check the question what you have put it as duplicate. There is no correct answer for that one. @CodingGorilla

Comment: I withdrew the close vote, I still think that is your best solution though.

Comment: ok i just want to apply border only to combobox not all the controls. I already tried what you have suggested.

Comment: I don't get it. You set the flat style and you don't like it, so you want to change it? Great, set it back to the system style so it looks like all other standard comboboxes. The flat style is an abomination in the first place.

Comment: Since the combo box doesn't use `OnPaint` method, you should handle `WM_PAINT` message yourself in `WndProc` and paint the borders yourself. For more information take a look at [`ComboBox.FlatComboAdapter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,79ca61e52b2766da). I shared a simple implementation in my answer.

Comment: It seems you have to use magic to get a normally looking ComboBox.

Comment: Related post - [How to change the BackColor of a ComboBox when DropdownStyle is DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36345082/465053)

Answer (score 18):

You can inherit from `ComboBox` and override [`WndProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and handle [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message and draw border for your combo box:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FlatCombo : ComboBox
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    Color borderColor = Color.Blue;
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT && DropDownStyle != ComboBoxStyle.Simple)
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
            {
                using (var p = new Pen(BorderColor))
                {
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);

                    var d = FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Popup ? 1 : 0;
                    g.DrawLine(p, Width - buttonWidth - d,
                        0, Width - buttonWidth - d, Height);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- In the above example I used fore color for border, you can add a `BorderColor` property or use another color.
- If you don't like the left border of dropdown button, you can comment that `DrawLine` method.
- You need to draw line when the control is `RightToLeft` from `(0, buttonWidth)` to `(Height, buttonWidth)`
- To learn more about how to render a flat combo box, you can take a look at source code of internal [`ComboBox.FlatComboAdapter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,79ca61e52b2766da) class of .Net Framework.

**Flat ComboBox**

You may also like [Flat ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976649/3110834):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

CodingGorilla has the right answer, derive your own control from ComboBox and then paint the border yourself.

Here's a working example that paints a 1 pixel wide dark gray border:

```
class ColoredCombo : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Custom combobox border example]
Normal on the left, my example on the right.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to draw the border yourself in the Parent control's Paint Event:

```
    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
        Panel1.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, ComboBox1.Left - 1, ComboBox1.Top - 1, ComboBox1.Width + 1, ComboBox1.Height + 1)
    End Sub
```

Comment: In my case the parent container was the form itself. C# equivalent code: `this.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, combo1EClientVersion.Left - 1, combo1EClientVersion.Top - 1, combo1EClientVersion.Width + 1, combo1EClientVersion.Height + 1);`

Comment: I guess we need to use `CreateGraphics()` instead of `CreateGraphics`.