# How to change border property of controller in other application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application A that listen an application B (using Hook)

[image: [Application A]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Qws.png)

ListBox 1 = All application in my desktop with Button or TextBox

[image: [Application B]]

As you can see I already have Red Rectangle, I can use two method :

```
var dc = GetWindowDC((LBListControl.SelectedItem as Data).Value);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 0,0,50,20);
                g.Dispose();
                g.ReleaseHdc(dc);
            }
            // paintedRectangle = lRectangle[i];
            //ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(paintedRectangle, SystemColors.Highlight, FrameStyle.Dashed);
```

// -> Second Method. 
It's function that I call when I change my ListBox.SelectedIndex

```
private void LBListControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PaintRedRectangle(LBListControl.SelectedIndex);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {

            }
        }
```

lRectangle is a list that contains X, Y of my button / textbox (Widht / Height are set by myself).

I heard that using the handle i could change BorderStyle / BorderColor of a controller. If it's true I didn't found a thing about that and I would like to know if you know something.

Else how could I supress my RedRectangle when I want to show someone else ?

BTW : Using g.ReleaseHdc(dc); doesn't work parameter is invalid (Don't know why)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at [Change border-color in TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) and [Change border-color in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886006/3110834) for example.

Comment: I guess you don't need to change the border-color and it's enough for you to draw a border **around** them, in fact on their parent graphics object.

Comment: Change Border-Color of TextBox and Button when i chose them in my ListBox (the right listbox on my Application A picture).
Edit : Didn't see it was a link ! Gonna read it (didn't find it at first)

Comment: Ok so my bad, i read it yesterday via : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768938/change-the-bordercolor-of-the-textbox (You commented here too :) )
But I didn't try the method you shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466067/change-border-color-in-textbox-c-sharp/39420512#39420512

EDIT : Yeah I do want to draw a border around them (that's why i'm drawing a RedRectangle, but I can't erase it to only have one rectangle

Comment: You may also find this post useful [Put dotted border around all controls.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40209045/3110834)

Comment: Well, it's funny because I read this post too yet I didn't want to use an invisible form. My Application B is only to test my Application A. I'm gonna use it to hook an other application.

Comment: There is no invisible form. It's a transparent panel. This way you can draw over all controls.

Comment: All controls in the main context ? Does that work for third-party application ?

Comment: No. Just for your main application. For third party application, you need to use a transparent form.

Comment: Thank you :) You are really helpful ! I must use a transparent form then

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Reza Aghaei I made it !

I created a new form :

```
public partial class InvisibleFrame : Form
    {
        public InvisibleFrame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BackColor = Color.Lime;
            TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
    }
```

That I call here :

```
private void PaintRedRectangle(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            ci.Location = new Point(lRectangle[i].X, lRectangle[i].Y);
            ci.Size = new Size(10, 10);
            ci.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ci.BringToFront();
            ci.Show();
        }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            ci = new InvisibleFrame();
            PaintRedRectangle(i);
        }
    }
```

And I choose the button and the TextBox I want to hook :

```
private void BTHookTB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        ControlHook TextBoxHook = new ControlHook
        {
            Text = LBListControl.SelectedItem.ToString(),
            Position = lRectangle[LBListControl.SelectedIndex],
        };
        lControlHook.Add(TextBoxHook);
        LabelTBHook.Text = "TextBox : " + lControlHook[1].Text;
        BTHookTB.Enabled = false;
        BTReset.Enabled = true;
        BTHook.Enabled = true;
        LBListControl.Enabled = false;
        ci.Hide();
    }
}
```

I hide it.