# How to change a ComboBox outline border using SendMessage?

Tags: c++, combobox

```
SendMessage(hwnd, ...)
```

Im trying to achieve a result similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59915923/12733526

But using SendMessage to change the current "blue outline" to another color:

[image]

Comment: That other answer is custom-drawing the ComboBox. So what makes you think a simple `SendMessage()` will let you change the coloring?

Comment: I could change the text, background and selection color, I'm asking if its also possible the border color.

Comment: There is no system-defined message for changing a ComboBox's border coloring.

Comment: Do you know if theres any message to change the x/y position of the dropdown?

Comment: There is no message for that. But you can use `GetComboBoxInfo()` to get the `HWND` of the drop-down list, and then you can move it around with `SetWindowPos()` as desired.

Comment: I tried it but for a short period of time the drop-down is shown before it got moved, what else do you suggest?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish in the first place? And what does this have to do with colors? You should post a new question

Comment: Trying to adjust the position according to the button width